# Change shellinabox cursor configuration

Tags: css, ssh

Is there a way to change the default block cursor used by Shellinabox to a vertical bar?

Using Chrome's inspector tool, I found this div:

```
<div id="cursize" style="left: 675.5px; top: 160px; visibility: hidden;">143x20</div>
```

but altering the value does nothing.

There is nothing about a cursor size in the page's [styles.css file](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox/blob/e6c25e84bc662797c7382500f136bb74874c2500/shellinabox/styles.css) or any of the config files found in `/etc/shellinabox/options-available`.

---

*If you know of a better place to ask a question like this, please tell me.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those inline styles have been generated dynamically through means of something like JavaScript. Considering they are generated **dynamically**, simply manipulating their values won't reflect any change.

Having said that, you **can** override them with the **[`!important`](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)**  declaration. Typically `!important` should only be used as a **[last resort](https://memeexplorer.com/cache/846.jpg)**, but inline styles have the second-highest level of [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), and `!important` is the only way to override them.

Using something like the following should work for you:

```
#cursize {
  left: 500px !important;
  top: 100px !important;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This did work, but it turns out the cursor mentioned in the css files is for a [popup box showing the terminal size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u25Oq.jpg)

Comment: I take that back.. All I had to do was dig a little more into the html structure and find the actual cursor. I changed the `width` to 1 without even needing to use `!important` and it worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem; glad to help. Remember that you can always use `!important` as a 'test' to ensure that you have the right element targeted; it will always work, unless there is also another selector targeting the same element with its own `!important` declaration =]